# how can I get the text on submission with bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, anchor

Normally I would be writing dropdown with `select` and `option` but somehow I came across to this by using bootstrap dropdown which uses anchor

Using a sample in bootstrap

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="get-value-btn">Get value / text</button>
```

If I want to get the value when I click the `Get value / text` with `jQuery` how can I do it though? Normally with select, it's straight forward but I never done it this way.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advices.

Comment: Bootstrap dropdowns are not the real dropdowns hence there is no option to hold values and/or texts. You can still store them using jQuery `data-*` attributes but that's not what Bootstrap dropdown is for. You can tell Bootstrap dropdowns don't show you the selected option after you select one. Anyway, what's wrong with normal selects with `.form-control` style from Bootstrap?

Comment: @DavidLiang thanks for the response, but even if with `data-*` how can I know which value is selected though?  There is nothing wrong with the normal selects with `.form-control` since that's what I normally use too. It's just this part isn't written by me and I found a bug. To be short, I try not to change much if not needed because I am not sure if it'll cause lots other issues for whatever reason.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/vsd756xj/26/. I haven't had time to finish it but here is the basic idea: you store the values via data attributes, then you have to hook up many events to 1) update dropdown toggler's text to be the selected one 2) add `.active` class on the selected option and remove it from all others. Once those are setup, then it's just matter of writting more jQuerys to get the option that has `.active` class and remove the value stored in dataattribute. It's just a lot of work. Again, Bootstrap dropdowns are good for styles but not for storing values like form element

Comment: @DavidLiang pretty much got your idea.  Thanks thanks a lot :D